# Using the LIKE operator in MYSQL voids the "id > ? operation"

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using the like operator to select where like %x% and using the id > ? at the same time but it doesn't work for whatever reason where I keep pulling in the same row of information.

My code is concise and works well I think but the like operator is making it so I keep pulling in the same data (I used = and it worked). Any help please, thank you.

```
  var query = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1 = 1';
  var arr = [];

  if(typeof(req.body.category) == 'string' && req.body.category.trim() !== '') { 
    // query += ' AND category LIKE ? OR title LIKE ?'; //doesnt work keep pulling in same data
    // arr.push('%' + req.body.category + '%', '%' + req.body.category + '%');  //doesnt work keep pulling in same data
    // query += ' AND category = ? OR title = ?'; //works 
    // arr.push(req.body.category, req.body.category); //works
  } 

  if(typeof(req.body.reset_index) == 'boolean' && req.body.reset_index == true) { 
    req.session.last_id_main_products = 0;
  }

  query += ' AND id > ?';
  arr.push(req.session.last_id_main_products);
  
  if(
    typeof(req.body.longitude) == 'number' &&
    typeof(req.body.latitude) == 'number' && 
    typeof(req.body.if_location) == 'boolean' && req.body.if_location == true
  ) { 
    var left_long = req.body.longitude - 0.3;
    var right_long = req.body.longitude + 0.3;
    var upper_lat = req.body.latitude + 0.3;
    var lower_lat = req.body.latitude - 0.3;
    query += ' AND (room_geo_longitude > ? AND room_geo_longitude < ?) AND (room_geo_latitude > ? AND room_geo_latitude < ?)';
    arr.push(left_long, right_long, lower_lat, upper_lat);
  }

  query += ' AND hidden = false LIMIT 1';

  pool.query(query, arr, (err, result) => { 

    if(err) {
      res.json(err);
      return;
    }

    if(result.length > 0) { 
      req.session.last_id_main_products = result[result.length - 1].id;
    }

    res.json({ 
      room_products: result, 
      query: query,
      arr: arr
    });

  });
```

UPDATE: When using query, use parentheses around specific types of operations or else will return bad data.

Comment: Have you tried using `pool.escape()` instead... `query += " AND category LIKE '%" + pool.escape(req.body.category) + "%'` I think the problem you're having is that the auto string escaping is likely replacing those wildcard characters.

Comment: im not sure but i think it might be because i forgot some curly braces but i will try this